# How to query based on datetimeproperty in app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a bunch of posts:

```
PostModel(db.Model)
    ...
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now = True)
```

and the postmodel.html for rendering each post had

```
{{p.created.strftime("%Y %m %d")}}
```

And eventually I want to sort the posts based on the time they were last modified by month. Would the query for, say all the posts created December of 2013, look something like

```
posts = PostModel.all().filter("created", 2013 12)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the order method to add a sort order to the query.

For e.g. you can use the `.order('-created')` in a cascaded form to your above statement.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to the filter for DatetimeProperty is a Datetime object.